# Map function in Purr

Tags: r, list, dictionary, ggplot2

I am trying to create line plots for each PAT using map and ggplot. The following code doesnt work , i have also tried passing in a list

```
Lb1 <- labs[, c("PAT","RES","PARAMCD","AVISITN","LBSTNRHI")]
subj <- unique(lb1$PAT)
p1 <- map(.x = subj, .f = ~ lb1 %>%  
  filter(SUBJID == subj[.x] & PARAMCD %in% c("CA", "HGB", "BILI", "BILDIR")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(VISIT,AVAL,color = PARAMCD)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle(label = subj[.x]))
p1
```

Comment: You need to pass a data.frame to ggplor2, if could share your data

Comment: I am passing the data frame lb1 after filtering for PAT and PARAMCD %in% c("CA", "HGB", "BILI", "BILDIR"))

Comment: (1) You define `Lb1` (upper-case "L") and later reference `lb1 %>% ...` (lower-case "L"). (2) We know nothing about the data, so *guessing* what should be happening is highly inferential. (3) You are creating a `list` into `p1`, are you expecting multiple plots? It's really hard to tell. (4) *"code doesnt work"* does nothing: *what* doesn't work? Does it plot something that looks wrong? Does it produce warnings/errors? Does it do nothing and just return to the prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always difficult to help if you don't share the data.

I can spot few error/inconsistencies in your code.

1. First, you have unique values of `PAT` column in `subj` (`subj <- unique(lb1$PAT)`) but later in `map` you `filter` the `SUBJID` column with those values. Is that correct? Or should you have unique values of `SUBJID` in `subj` i.e `subj <- unique(lb1$SUBJID)`.
2. You are passing the values of `subj` in `map` so I don't think `subj[.x]` makes sense. `.x` already has the value that you want so you can use it directly.

Try -

```
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- map(.x = subj, .f = ~ lb1 %>%  
            filter(SUBJID == .x & PARAMCD %in% c("CA", "HGB", "BILI", "BILDIR")) %>% 
            ggplot(aes(VISIT,AVAL,color = PARAMCD)) +
            geom_point() +
            geom_line() +
            ggtitle(.x)
          )
p1
```

Comment: SUBJ and PAT is a typo from side.  i used .x as you suggested and i was able to create all the plots. Thank you!

Comment: p1 is a list of about 12 ggplot objects. I am using patchwork library to put all the graphs next to each other. I am using the following code which doesn’t look the most efficient way. Any suggestions? 
library(patchwork)
testxx <- p1[[1]] + p1[[2]] +
          p1[[3]] + p1[[4]] +
          p1[[5]] + p1[[6]] +
          p1[[7]] + p1[[8]] +
          p1[[9]] + p1[[10]] +
          p1[[11]] + p1[[12]]

Comment: You can use `patchwork::wrap_plots(p1, ncol = 4, nrow = 3)`